# chrome.windows.oncreated vs chrome.windows.create, which callback function will be returned first?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know about 2 callback event in chrome.windows function:

```
chrome.windows.create(object createData, function callback)
```

and

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function callback)
```

Which callback function will be returned first if I create a new window and also listen to it when created to do something ?
Thanks.

Comment: it shouldnt be too hard to test?

Comment: It's not documented so don't rely on the order. It may change between versions.

Comment: My work is declare variable in chrome.windows.create and check it in chrome.windows.onCreated, maybe the async make me confused. After some test I figured out windows.create callback function returned before the onCreated's callback one. Thanks.